# How to activate the inactive RAM in a server?

Tags: windows-xp, memory, 64-bit, bios, dell-precision

In a Dell Precision server, there are 8GB RAM. The OS is Windows XP 64-bit.

Originally, everything is working fine. Both BIOS and Windows are able to detect 8GB RAM. One day when I power up the server, the BIOS shows a message "the amount of system memory has changed. Press FX to continue". After the server finished booting up, Windows shows 4GB RAM only.

I rebooted the server and checked the BIOS. In the memory details page, it shows 4GB RAM in the summary. But below the summary column, it shows that it detected 8 x 1GB memory sticks in the system.

I have installed [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) in Windows. It also detected 8 x 1GB RAM. But Windows's system properties window only shows 4GB.

Why the BIOS suddenly fail to detect 4GB RAM? Is this a hardware failure? How can I activate the inactive 4GB RAM? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like hardware failure if BIOS doesn't report 8GB. Have you tried fully powering it down?

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes, I have shutdown the server many times. In BIOS, it shows 4GB in the summary column, but under the summary column it shows that there are 8 X 1GB RAM. Have you seen this kind of calculation error in BIOS before?

Comment: Try unseating and re-seating the ram. If that fails, run a memory tester application, such as Memtest, which will test for bad memory.

Comment: Your RAM might be defective (or it might be the motherboard, or a bug in your BIOS... is there any BIOS updates available?). Did you try the RAM bar in another machine? Or another RAM bar in this machine?

Comment: Also, has there been any hardware changes recently?

Comment: Check the BIOS memory settings, make sure "memory remapping" (sometimes called "memory hole remapping") is ON.

Comment: Have you tried a different memory stick?  This will confirm if its a hardware or software problem.  There is no such thing as "inactive" memory when dealing with Windows XP 64 bit.

Comment: @Ramhound If the OP was using Windows XP 32bit - then XP will refuse to use anything above ~4GB of RAM - regardless of how much physical RAM they have. PAE, for Windows 32bit, is only licensed for the server editions.

Comment: @NathanAdams - Except the author ISN"T using a 32-bit installation of Windows they are using a 64-bit version of Windows XP.  I assume the user is smart enough to know the different between the two versions.

Comment: @Davidw Thank you! Unseating and re-seating the RAM solved the problem. Please put your answer in the answer section so that I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unseating and re-seating the ram. If that fails, run a memory tester application, such as Memtest, which will test for bad memory.